# Skaffold run cannot locate specified Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy a Docker image to Kubernetes on gcloud using Skaffold.
For a minimal example I have the following files in a directory:

1. Dockerfile
2. skaffold.yaml
3. k8s/deployment.yaml

My Dockerfile is very simple:

```
FROM scratch
ADD bin/helloworld /helloworld
CMD ["/helloworld"]
```

My skaffold.yaml is:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1alpha1
kind: Config
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  artifacts:
  - imageName: test
    workspace: .
  local: {}
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s/*
```

When I do `skaffold run` in the root of the directory I get this error:

```
Starting build...
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.024kB
[31mERRO[0m[0000] run: running skaffold steps: build: build step: running build: docker build: Error response from daemon: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

I am on Windows 10, using skaffold v0.3.0

A normal `docker build .` command works fine and I tested `skaffold run` on a different Ubuntu machine with the same directory shared using git and it works fine there. What could be the issue?

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/149)

Comment: Thanks @fernandezcuesta, I assume you meant I should try to specify the skaffold.yaml file in the command. I tried `skaffold run -f skaffold.yaml`, but sadly still get the same error

Comment: I meant checking if the skaffold version contains the patch mentioned there

Comment: If I read it correct they discuss the examples and their pathing. Anyway I upgraded to skaffold 0.4 and changed the yaml to that standard and now it works. Still no idea why 0.3 did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around the issue by upgrading to skaffold 0.4.0 and changing the skaffold.yaml to:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1alpha2
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - imageName: test
    workspace: .
  local: {}
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s/*
```